# django filter one object from model instance on serialization

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have django model with m2m field, and I want to customise serializer so I can filter only needed data. Code is shown bellow.

`models.py`:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    field = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

`serializers.py`:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return {"""... processing User's fields..."""}

class ExampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerialzier):
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        user = self.context
        result = {... some fields ...}
        if instance.field == "some_value":
            ### IN THIS CASE THERE ARE ONLY TWO USERS, NEVER MORE###
            result['users'] = UserSerializer(instance.users.exclude(id=user.id)[0]).data
        else:
            result['users'] = ...
```

`views.py`:

```
ExampleSerializer(Example.objects.all(), many=True, context=user).data
```

Not sure you need anything else, but feel free to ask.

So the problem is that in case if `type` is "some_value" I want to get only one user which is not the one who initiated this call, it works fine but looks ugly and I'm not sure that on highload would perform fast enough. Of course I could write another custom serializer especially for this case, but still looking for the best solution.

Is there any built-in option in python?

And I'm noticed that serializers aren't really fast for such an operations, is there any way I could save up time? Something like indexes and etc?

Thanks in advance for your responds!

Comment: `type` is a python builtin. It should never be `"some value"`

Comment: @HåkenLid type is custom name field, in my models name is different but thanks for remark